# how to use io.getclump.Clump.source method warper a future list service?

Tags: scala, future

I'm try [Clump](https://github.com/getclump/clump).source warper my future list function as follows:

```
case class User(id: Int, foodId: Int)

val listUsersResult = List(User(1, 10), User(2, 20), User(3, 30))         
//simulate a service                                                  
def usersService(userGroup:Int): Future[List[User]] = Future(listUsersResult)

//attempt clump service
val userSource = Clump.source(usersService _)(_.id)
```

Compiler errors:

```
Error:(26, 48) Cannot construct a collection of type Int with elements of type Int based on a collection of type Nothing.
  val userSource = Clump.source(usersService _)(_.id)
                                               ^
Error:(26, 48) not enough arguments for method source: (implicit cbf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Nothing,Int,Int], implicit ec: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext)io.getclump.ClumpSource[Int,spice.functional.monad.User].
Unspecified value parameters cbf, ec.
  val userSource = Clump.source(usersService _)(_.id)
                                           ^
```

Could someone explain the both errors means? thanks

Comment: What is `Clump` ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh, Clump is toolkit, help Futures combined more clear, it homepage at [there](https://github.com/getclump/clump).My company project used it and I want make some understand.If you interesting it, just look above link please.The question is freshman, maybe you can achieve it!